# how to acces nested objects in blade templates

Tags: laravel

Let me show you what I have.

```
//Post Controller

public function showPost(Post $post)
{
$albums = $post->album()->with('photos')->get();
$comments = $post->comments()->where('approved', '=', 1)->get();
$this->layout->title = $post->title;
$this->layout->main = View::make('home')->nest('content','posts.single', compact('post', 'comments','albums'));
}
```

mysql sentence executed correctly

string 'select * from `albums` where `albums`.`id` = '{"id":19,"title":"Post no 19","read_more":"Lorem i'... (length=786)
string 'select * from `albums` where `albums`.`post_id` = '19'' (length=54)
string 'select * from `images` where `images`.`album_id` in ('4')' (length=57)

I want to access the Photo object in blade, everything parses to the template but when I try to get the Photos

@foreach($albums->Photos as $photo)

**Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$Photos (View:**

// post model

```
public function album()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Album');

    }
```

//album model

```
public function Photos(){

        return $this->hasMany('Image');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@foreach($albums->Photos()->get() as $photo)
{{$photo->attribute}}
@endforeach
```

You need to call the function that holds the relationship then use

> get()

method to return an Eloquent Collection and then iterate it with a foreach loop.

Comment: No problem, you can also try to create an accessor for more info go [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($albums as $album)
    @foreach($album->Photos as $photo)
    <p>{{ $photo->image }}</p>
    @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

THats the answer